# Which line of the code make the reference count of a shared_ptr increasing?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I am looking for a way that determine which line of code is responsible for increasing reference count of a **shared_ptr**? for example, imagine a condition where I have a smart pointer and reference count of its is 12. I tend to know which line of the c++ code or assignment operator in my project is responsible for, whenever it was being 13.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Debugger.  Breakpoint.  Breakpoint condition on reference count being 13.

Comment: Passing shared_ptr to a function by value will keep on increasing count.
To avoid this , you can pass shared_ptr by reference.

Answer (score 4):

This is standard-library-implementation-dependent, as the implementation of shared_ptr is not part of the language standard.

Of course, it has to be a line that gets executed on construction, assignment and copy construction. Look for those three in library source files.

If you really must see an example, GCC's libstdc++' code for shared ptr is here:

- [bits/shared_ptr_base.h](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/shared_ptr_base.h)
- [bits/shared_ptr.h](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/shared_ptr.h)

but it ain't pretty....

Answer (score 3):

The reference count of a `shared_ptr` is the number of `shared_ptr` objects which share common ownership. So whenever you create a new `shared_ptr` using a constructor which takes a `weak_ptr` or an lvalue of `shared_ptr`, and whenever you assign an lvalue `shared_ptr` to another `shared_ptr`, you're increasing the reference count.

Notice that copying (actually moving) an rvalue of type `shared_ptr` does not modify the reference count, because the rvalue is moved from (emptied) and thus the reference is transferred rather than added.